# Getting an index from a column, then using it in to get a value from the other columns for a large file

Tags: python, regex

I have a very large file consisting of many lines and rows. To simplify my question, let's assume that there are 201 columns. The first column is like that `AB:CD:EF:GH` and other columns are like that `1:2:3:4`. The delimiters are the same, as it is seen. The pattern of all columns are supposed to be same. If there are 3 delimiter for the first column, it means there are 3 delimiters for all other in a given line.

For example I would like to know the index of `EF` in first column of the line and use that index to get the `3` from the all of columns. The index of `EF` varies across the lines.

I used two split methods. However, since my file is really big, it generates a great bottleneck for my code. There are more than ten millions lines by the way.

```
with open("amkhepinizin.txt", "r") as theFile:
    for line in theFile:
        ind = line[0].split(":").index("EF")
        theList = []
        for j in range(1,202):
            theList.append(line[j].split(":")[ind])
        foo(theList)  # some processes
```

It works but it is kind of slow. I found out that split methods which is called about 200 times for each line cause the code to work slowly. I thought that I can fasten this by using regular expressions, which I had no idea at first. I tried to find out how I can use regex, but I could not.

Here is an small example of my file.

```
EF:AD:DP:GQ:PL    0/0:95,0:96:99:0,214,2836    0/1:103,0:103:99:0,229,3036
AD:EF:DP:GQ:PL    0/1:16,7:25:99:242:5,1,6     0/0:32,0:33:93:0,93,1102 
DP:GQ:EF          99:533,0,422:1               99:310,0,1129:6
::EF:DP:          ::::                         0::0::
```

So basically, I would like to get `0/0` and `0/1` from first line; then `16,7` and `32,0` from the second line and `1` and `6` from the third line. `""` and `0` from the fourth line.

Could you please help me how to implement regex in my code.

If you think regex does not fasten my code, I would appreciate other suggestions.

Comment: First off, what? Second off is it Java, PHP or Python??? Looks like python only to me so I removed the other tags.

Comment: Show us a relevant (or example) portion of the file and what the expected output is and it'll be a lot easier to help you

Comment: I thought that language does not matter. I just want to learn how to write the correct regex string.

Comment: @KiviKivit if you give us a sample of say 10 lines (with expected output) we can better assist you.

Comment: I added a small example.

Comment: @KiviKivit it's sort of unclear what the relationship between the identifiers and the values are. For example, in the third line, how does `DP:GQ:EF` correspond to `1` and `6` being captured?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have just corrected it. Sorry for this

Comment: `line[0]` is just the first character of the line; I don't see how `ind = line[0].split(":").index("EF")` can ever work.

Answer (score 0):

It might speed up your code to use some generators:

```
import re

data = """
EF:AD:DP:GQ:PL    0/0:95,0:96:99:0,214,2836    0/1:103,0:103:99:0,229,3036
AD:EF:DP:GQ:PL    0/1:16,7:25:99:242:5,1,6     0/0:32,0:33:93:0,93,1102 
DP:GQ:EF          26:99:533,0,422:1            39:99:310,0,1129:6
::EF:DP:          ::::                         0::0::
"""

rx_needle = 'EF'

rx_lines = re.compile(r'.+')
rx_split = re.compile(r'\s{2,}')

def item_getter(line, needle):
    parts = rx_split.split(line)

    try:
        ind = parts[0].split(':').index(needle)
        values = (p[ind] for part in parts[1:] for p in [part.split(':')])
        return values
    except ValueError:
        return None

for line in rx_lines.finditer(data):
    values = item_getter(line.group(0), rx_needle)
    # do whatever you want to do with values here
    print(list(values))
```

Here, the idea is to use a generator to find the next line with `re.finditer()` and use another generator to get the specific values from that line (given the needle is found).
Advantage is that you can stop at a specific time in the future (let's say after 1000 lines or something) and that only small(er) amounts of memory are used.

---

A speed example:

```
def t():
    for line in rx_lines.finditer(data):
        values = item_getter(line.group(0), rx_needle)

import timeit
s = timeit.timeit(t, number=10**5)
print(s)
# 3.28 s
```

So to run the function against 400k lines, it takes about 3 seconds.

Comment: the issue is I am not asking how to use regex to "split lines". I already take the lines from the file one by one and then process it, although i did not write here exactly how I did. I am concerned in splitting with ":". It is called 200 times for each line.